# EF6 + npgsql + CodeFirst doesn't work with geometry

Tags: entity-framework-6, postgis, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql

We're trying to use EF6 + CodeFirst with a PostGIS database.

```
PostgreSQL v9.3.10
PostGIS v2.1.3
npgsql v3.2.2.0
EntityFramework6.Npgsql v3.1.1.0
```

My simple models without geometries work fine with `Add-Migrations` but when I add a `DbGeometry` property `Add-Migrations` fails with

```
Not supported edm type: Edm.Geometry
at Npgsql.NpgsqlProviderManifest.GetStoreType(TypeUsage edmType)
at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.StructuralTypeMappingGenerator.MapTableColumn(EdmProperty property, String columnName, Boolean isInstancePropertyOnDerivedType)
```

Googling I found these post at the GitHub of npgsql:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/623 and
https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/issues/18

These posts are from May 2015. I can't imagine nobody has found a solution yet for this problem. We can't be the first team in years that is doing `EF6+CodeFirst` with `PostGIS`.

So please advice how to continue or suggest a different provider which is working.